# Split a string and add to DataGridView

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a string like so:

```
"{[Entry Number: 1 | @AppUser: James | @AppTimeDate: 5/21/2018 | @AppText: A lot of multiline text here]}{[Entry Number: 2 | @AppUser: John | @AppTimeDate: 5/22/2018 | @AppText: More multiline text here]}"
```

I want to get this string into a DataGridView like so:

```
------------------------------
|Name     |Text              | -This is the header
------------------------------
|James    |A lot of multiline| -This is all one row for James
|5/21/2018|text here         |
------------------------------
|John     |More multiline    | -This is all another row for John
|5/21/2018|text here         |
------------------------------
```

Can anyone provide me an example of how this would be accomplished? I did a lot of googling, but I can't seem to find an example of how I would accomplish something like this.

I've tried doing this so far, but I keep getting a "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" error:

```
Dim RawNote As String = txtNotes.Text
Dim Splitter As String = "{[Entry Number: "

Dim substrings() As String = Regex.Split(RawNote, Splitter)
For Each match As String In substrings
    MsgBox(match)
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Linq, take these steps:

- Split the input string in distinct `Entries`
- Eliminate the useless text parts
- Split each entry to extract a list of its elements (`Fields`)
- Remove the unused text parts (`@AppText`, `@AppTimeDate` etc.)
- Generates the new string array with the specified format
- Add the string arrays to a DataGridView rows

**Note:**
*This code assumes there's a* `DataGridView` *already setup with two text columns*.

```
Dim RawNote As String = "{[Entry Number: 1 | @AppUser: James | @AppTimeDate: 5/21/2018 | @AppText: A lot of multiline text here]}" &
                        "{[Entry Number: 2 | @AppUser: John | @AppTimeDate: 5/22/2018 | @AppText: More multiline text here]}"

Dim InputList As List(Of String()) =
        RawNote.Split(New String() {"]}{["}, StringSplitOptions.None).
                Select(Function(part) part.Replace("{[", "").Replace("]}", "")).
                Select(Function(elm) elm.Split("|"c).
                                         Select(Function(str) str.Remove(0, str.IndexOf(":"c) + 1)).
                                         Skip(1).ToArray()).
                Select(Function(f) New String() {f(0) + Environment.NewLine + f(1), f(2)}).ToList()

DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
DataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells

For Each row As String() In InputList
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
Next
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I'm scared to try this method because of the downvote :( but it looks like it would work.

Comment: @Jason Mills  I have no idea. But don't be scared, it will not bite :). However, this code relies on the fact that the string format will be exactly how you presented it. Otherwise, it will not work. Of course you can adapt it to whatever format you want.

Comment: Hey Jimi, I actually get an error for this code :(: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Also, yes the code definitely makes sense! I had to stare at it to figure out how it works, but it definitely makes sense!

Comment: @Jason Mills  Well, tell me what error you get. Is the source string exactly as shown here? My test does complete without any error, as you can see in the image. Of course you must already have a `DataGridView` setup with two text columns.

Comment: Jimi, I'm stupid. I forgot to add my columns. Thank you, this does work absolutely beautifully!

Comment: @Jason Mills  I'm glad you got it to work. However, you could also create the columns at run time. It will be more flexible, in case you have more fields to add or you need to insert CheckBox or Button columns.

Answer (score 1):

I get an error with your code; however I am not familiar with Regex. A simple String.Split will accomplish the same thing. The .Split overload I used takes a Sting array. We only need an array of 1 element.The array is initialized right in the Dim statement. The second parameter is necessary. With this start maybe you can do the rest.

```
Private Sub ParseString()
        Dim RawNote As String = "{[Entry Number: 1 | @AppUser: James | @AppTimeDate: 5/21/2018 | @AppText: A lot of multiline text here]}{[Entry Number: 2 | @AppUser: John | @AppTimeDate: 5/22/2018 | @AppText: More multiline text here]}"
        Dim Splitter() As String = {"{[Entry Number: "}
        Dim substrings() As String = RawNote.Split(Splitter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        For Each match As String In substrings
            MsgBox(match)
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Mary, it's you again! My savior!